# Google plus hidden menu style

Tags: menu

What is menu style used name used in google plus (web). Hidden main navigation common to mobile but used sparingly in web. I'm interested in the name of the style and if possible some other examples. Fab.com has something similar too.

[image]

Comment: Typically, a navigation drawer, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This Menu style is generally referred as "Sliding Menu", "slide-in" or "Slide-out" menu.

I will not say its a standard name, but people generally call it so. I recently discovered this.

You can find usage [here](http://www.auipatterns.com/2013/03/sliding-menu.html), [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/44603/should-slide-in-out-navigation-be-restricted-to-tablet-mobile), [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/17/horizontal-slide-out-menu/) and [here](http://reviews.cnet.com/2300-3513_7-10014131.html).

Comment: This is a bit brief. Is this *actually* the name it goes by, or just your term for it? If it is used commonly then can you provided details of how you know this?

Comment: Just updated answer with required details.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you. Using jQuery animation you can simply create Google like new menu. HTML and CSS are simple for this you can check working demo and explanation of code here http://www.infotuts.com/google-like-new-menu-jquery-and-css/

Comment: OP is not asking *how* to implement it in jQuery - the question is about the terminology as to what it is called. Are you able to answer that part of the question?